# Haskell function to reverse function call

Tags: haskell

I have a lambda `\x f -> f x` that is being used in a `foldM` operation, where `x` is a value and `f :: a -> b`.

Is there a built-in function that does this?

Can I replace

```
foldM (\x f -> f x) ...
```

with some `f'`

```
foldM f' ...
```

I thought that `flip` would do this, but it takes three arguments (`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`)

It is probably similar to `|>` in F#.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `flip id` or `flip ($)` (as `($)` is just a special `id` for functions):

```
Prelude> flip id 3 (+2)
5
Prelude> flip ($) 7 (>10)
False
```

This is an interesting use of partial application: `id f x` with `f` being a function is just `f x`. Obviously, this is *also* the same as `(flip id) x f`, so `flip id` is the function you are looking for.

If you feel adventurous, try inferring the type of `flip id` or `flip ($)` manually. It's fun :)

Comment: Wow, that took me about 5 minutes with paper and pen to work out how `id`'s `a -> a` signature could somehow map onto `flip`'s expecting something with `a -> b -> c`. It might be worth going into that a little bit!

Comment: @Len: It becomes clearer once you see that when applied to functions, `id` is the same as `($)`

Comment: That's very true! The "a-ha" moment for me was realising that I should see `a -> b -> c` as the `a -> (b -> c)` that it is, and then matched that to `id`'s `a' -> a'` and found that `a = a' = (b -> c)`—I was looking too much at the differences in arity and couldn't get past it.

Comment: Thanks. Haskell is a cool language, but I feel like my brain is in a maze of twisty little passages, all alike ...

Comment: I didn't know about lamdbabot. I've been using Hoogle. Thanks.

Comment: @Ralph: There's also pointfree package on Hackage. `cabal install pointfree` and `pointfree "\a b -> b a"`.

Comment: @Niklas B.: Thank you for interesting information. Now I need to work with paper and pencil.

Comment: @RottenBrain: Glad this answer enlightens people even 2 years after its appearance :)

Comment: @Niklas B.: It happens with great answers :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's called `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`, e.g. `flip (>) 3 5 == True`. More infos and source on hackage: [flip](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aflip).

What you want is simply to reverse the arguments of function application, right?
Well, since `($)` is function application, by using flip you may write `flip ($) ::  b -> (b -> c) -> c`. Let see what happens. Here is the source for the two prelude functions:

```
-- from Hackage:
($)                     :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x                   =  f x

-- from Hackage:
flip                    :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y              =  f y x
```

So, basically if you put together the types, `flip ($)` becomes

```
flip ($) :: 
  b        ->    -- type of x, argument of y and second argument of ($)
  (b -> c) ->    -- type of y, function applied by ($) as its first argument
  c        ->    -- result of the application "y x"
```

If you follow the actual definitions of the functions:

```
flip ($) = (\f x y -> f y x) ($)    -- from flip's def.
         = \x y -> ($) y x          -- partial application
         = y x                      -- from ($)'s def.
```