# Common name for reverse application function

Tags: haskell

Does the function

```
(#) x f = f x
```

similar to the unix pipe, does this have a common name/symbol, other than `#` which I just made up?

Comment: Hoogle it based on the type signature?

Comment: Some folk call it `|>`, but after a goodly while, you stop wanting it and use `.` and `$` a lot more.

Comment: Interestingly, [`diagrams` made it up the same way as you](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.0.0.1/docs/Diagrams-Util.html)!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815896/haskell-function-to-reverse-function-call/10815923

Comment: This function has been around since the late 90's with the name (#) - it was used by Erik Meijer and Daan Leijen to achieve an OO-like notation for scripting COM components and Peter Thiemann used it for the Wash library. At this time Hugs was more popular than GHC, but as people moved from Hugs to GHC (#) seemed to fall off the radar (possibly because GHC already used # for magical purposes). People sporadically request its inclusion in the Base Libs on the Libraries mailing list, but sadly its time seems to have passed.

Comment: To add more to comments by @stephentetley. The (#) makes more sense when a function has many arguments where last argument is the 'object' on which the function is being applied. For example,

'f x y z obj' 

can be written as 

'obj # f x y z' 

which looks like we are calling method f of object 'obj'.

Answer (score 5):

You can find it in the lens library as [`&`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html#v:-38-).

Comment: I would agree that this is the best answer if you want it pre-defined, but adding `lens` as a dependency is pretty extreme for such a simple operator.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest adding lens as a dependency just for this operator, but I would consider using the same name.

Comment: `#` is also already used for that purpose [elsewhere](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.0.0.1/docs/Diagrams-Util.html), and I rather prefer that symbol over `&`. `lens` is arguably a more "fundamental" reference than `diagrams`, but OTOH its operators are very much specific for accessor tasks.